# Hibernate with glassfish, oracle database and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, glassfish-3

I am learning `hibernate`, I am using `eclipse` as IDE and will be using `glassfish 3` as my app server and last but not least `Oracle 10g` will be the database I would be connecting to.

Could someone what are the jars required for hibernate and oracle database jars?

Thanks

Comment: If anyone is voting to close this post, kindly mention the reason or provide alternate links if exists. Thanks.

Comment: I'm downvoting this as this can be found using any online search engine. Therefore this question doesn't show real research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for hibernate you should include the following in your POM.  I really recommend you use something like Maven to build your project.  If you can't right now, search for the dependencies on http://mvnrepository.com/, which will at least tell you the jars you need and provide a download link as well.

```
    <!-- Hibernate for ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate uses this for auditing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>${evers.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I use

```
    <hibernate.version>4.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    <evers.version>4.1.0.Final</evers.version>
```

for the two versions. Envers is only really necessary if you need auditing (which is rather nice).  For Oracle, this should work:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Not sure what the correct version is for 10g.  Also, I am not familiar with glassfish, but the two above should get you going. Use the link above to find the appropriate jars you need.  Good luck with hibernate... when it works, it's the next big thing since sliced cheese, if it breaks... well, it's the spawn of hell.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add hibernate jar and oracle jdbc jar for your project.Here are the links to download this jars.

- [Hibernate download](http://www.hibernate.org/downloads)
- [Oracle JDBC download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html)